# Submit iPhone and iPad version of app with same name

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I want to submit my app to the App Store, and I have the iPhone and iPod version in one Xcode file, and the iPad version in another Xcode file. Can I submit both with the same name? Or how do I submit both apps/files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you developed your app in two XCode files, you'll have to submit two different apps to the store (maybe AppName and AppName HD).

If you developed them in one XCode file, then you could have different behavior for the iPad/iPhone, yet still one App Store submission. This is what I would recommend.

Comment: Thank you sir!! from here i know what to do :)

Comment: No problem! I'd recommend using only one XCode project. @LuisVillavicencio

Comment: Yes, i tried to make my app universal but i couldn't make it look the way it was supposed to. Thats the reason i made two projects @Dehli

Answer (score 1):

By "file", you mean "project", right?

You're not going to be able to submit two apps with the same name. Also, submitting two apps would mean going through the review process twice, and also fragmenting your reviews and ratings. The better approach is to make a single project, and make it handle all devices you want to support--either with multiple storyboards or nibs (old way) or size classes (new way).